# Accessing multiple apps with the same login (SSO)

Tags: .net-core, oauth, jwt, authorization, single-sign-on

I had one web site called **Fetch**, which was used by all our clients and it had all the features (starting from login to all services related to healthcare).

Now we have to build one more small site (called **Portal**) which is like ecommerce site, where user can order something from this site. It will use the same user base from Fetch (first site), so we are planning to give a **link in Portal site to access Fetch site** and we are omitting the login part in Portal site if they clicked on the link.

Image -
[image]

As per the above diagram -

- Fetch site and Portal site are **independently deployed**
- Portal site is using **FetchGateway** for validating the user in **Fetch DB**.
- Portal DB will store only order related information is what we are thinking for now.

Its a typical SSO kind of behavior is what i am expecting, and user details are stored in our Fetch DB only.

I am thinking to use OAuth2 for this.

**Questions**

*1. Do you think I should be using Open Id Connect as well even though i am validating the user in FetchDB.*

*2. Should I keep the identity things separate from Fetch as **AuthenticationService** and serve both the applications from this ?*

*3. Apart from these if you think any alternate solution, please let me know*

Comment: Hi All, i wud really appreciate if you share any thoughts on the above.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems like you need an Authorization Server — a separate service that is responsible for:

- holding all the identity data of your users,
- performing the authentication process.

Both your services can then call the Authorization Server to log a user in. The AS can establish a cookie-based session with the user, then reuse it when the user tries to log in from your other service (SSO).

As to whether you need OAuth or OIDC, the question is what your applications need. If your apps need only an access token to be able to call your backend APIs, then OAuth is enough. Adding OIDC to the mix will give your apps information about the logged-in user — her username, email address, information when she logged in, etc. If this is something that you need directly in the front-end app, then you will need OIDC as well.

Comment: Thanks Michal for the reply,  I have one problem with this approach,  i am storing login user details and role information of the user in client side as session storage,  once i redirected to the destination url, it will open in the new tab and it will not have the session storage values, so is it better to change it to localstorage or any other state server session storage ?

Comment: If you need to share this information, then you can keep it in the local storage. You can keep it on the server side, use OIDC and return this information in an ID token. Any application that will require that data and will not have it locally, can call your AS and get a new ID token.

Comment: Presently in my scenario i am storing the data in Local storage, for calling the AS, i need token generated from first tab to other tab, so thought storing in local storage makes more sense,  only concern is the security as its stored at the browser level, any suggestion to secure the token in local storage

Comment: There is only one way to secure tokens kept in the browser — don't keep them there. Unfortunately, it's not a joke, and if you're concerned with token security then you have to resort to cookie-based sessions and backend components that handle tokens. At Curity we've described this pattern, we call it the Token Handler: https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-overview/ We even provide some open-source components that you can use to set up this solution.